# How to replace a particular line in xml with the new one in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a requirement where I need to replace the element value with the new one and I dont want any other modification to be done to the file.

```
<mtn:test-case title='Power-Consist-Message'>
 <mtn:messages>
  <mtn:message sequence='4' correlation-key='0x0F04'>
  <mtn:header>
   <mtn:protocol-version>0x4</mtn:protocol-version>
   <mtn:message-type>0x0F04</mtn:message-type>
   <mtn:message-version>0x01</mtn:message-version>
   <mtn:gmt-time-switch>false</mtn:gmt-time-switch>
   <mtn:crc-calc-switch>1</mtn:crc-calc-switch>
   <mtn:encrypt-switch>false</mtn:encrypt-switch>
   <mtn:compress-switch>false</mtn:compress-switch>
   <mtn:ttl>999</mtn:ttl>
   <mtn:qos-class-of-service>0</mtn:qos-class-of-service>
   <mtn:qos-priority>2</mtn:qos-priority>
   <mtn:qos-network-preference>1</mtn:qos-network-preference>
```

this is how the xml file looks like, I want to replace 999 with "some other value", under s section, but when am doing that using formatter in ruby some other unwanted modifications are taking place, the code that am using is as belows

```
File.open(ENV['CadPath1']+ "conf\\cad-mtn-config.xml") do |config_file|
# Open the document and edit the file
config = Document.new(config_file)
    testField=config.root.elements[4].elements[11].elements[1].elements[1].elements[1].elements[11]
if testField.to_s.match(/<mtn:qos-network-preference>/)
   test=config.root.elements[4].elements[11].elements[1].elements[1].elements[1].elements[8].text="2"
# Write the result to a new file.
formatter = REXML::Formatters::Default.new
File.open(ENV['CadPath1']+ "conf\\cad-mtn-config.xml", 'w') do |result|
formatter.write(config, result)
end
end
end
```

when am writting the modifications to the new file, the xml file size is getting changed from 79kb to 78kb, is there any way to just replace the particular line in xml file and save changes without affecting the xml file.
Please let me know soon...

Comment: In future, please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Nokogiri as my XML/HTML parser of choice:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<EOT
<mtn:test-case title='Power-Consist-Message'>
 <mtn:messages>
  <mtn:message sequence='4' correlation-key='0x0F04'>
  <mtn:header>
   <mtn:protocol-version>0x4</mtn:protocol-version>
   <mtn:message-type>0x0F04</mtn:message-type>
   <mtn:message-version>0x01</mtn:message-version>
   <mtn:gmt-time-switch>false</mtn:gmt-time-switch>
   <mtn:crc-calc-switch>1</mtn:crc-calc-switch>
   <mtn:encrypt-switch>false</mtn:encrypt-switch>
   <mtn:compress-switch>false</mtn:compress-switch>
   <mtn:ttl>999</mtn:ttl>
   <mtn:qos-class-of-service>0</mtn:qos-class-of-service>
   <mtn:qos-priority>2</mtn:qos-priority>
   <mtn:qos-network-preference>1</mtn:qos-network-preference>
EOT
```

Notice that the XML is malformed, i.e., it doesn't terminate correctly.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

I'm using CSS accessors to find the `ttl` node. Because of some magic, Nokogiri's CSS ignores XML name spaces, simplifying finding nodes.

```
doc.at('ttl').content = '1000'
puts doc.to_xml


# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <test-case title="Power-Consist-Message">
# >>  <messages>
# >>   <message sequence="4" correlation-key="0x0F04">
# >>   <header>
# >>    <protocol-version>0x4</protocol-version>
# >>    <message-type>0x0F04</message-type>
# >>    <message-version>0x01</message-version>
# >>    <gmt-time-switch>false</gmt-time-switch>
# >>    <crc-calc-switch>1</crc-calc-switch>
# >>    <encrypt-switch>false</encrypt-switch>
# >>    <compress-switch>false</compress-switch>
# >>    <ttl>1000</ttl>
# >>    <qos-class-of-service>0</qos-class-of-service>
# >>    <qos-priority>2</qos-priority>
# >>    <qos-network-preference>1</qos-network-preference>
# >> </header></message></messages></test-case>
```

Notice that Nokogiri replaced the content of the `ttl` node. It also stripped the XML namespace info because the document didn't declare it correctly, and, finally, Nokogiri has added closing tags to make the document syntactically correct.

If you want the namespace to be declared in the output, you'll need to make sure it's there in the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just literally replace that value without affecting anything else about the XML file, even if (as pointed by the Tin Man above) that would mean leaving the original XML file malformed, you can do that with direct string manipulation using a regular expression.

Assuming there is guaranteed to only be one <mtn:ttl> tag in your XML document, you could just do:

```
doc = IO.read("somefile.xml")
doc.sub! /<mtn:ttl>.+?<\/mtn:ttl>/, "<mtn:ttl>some other value<\/mtn:ttl>" 
File.open("somefile.xml", "w") {|fh| fh.write(doc)}
```

If there might be more than one <mtn:ttl> tag, then this is trickier; how much trickier depends on how you want to figure out which tag(s) to change.

Comment: hey, there is one <mtn:ttl>some other value<\/mtn:ttl> under  <test-case title="Power-Consist-Message"> and another under <mtn:test-case title="Caution-Bulletin-Message"> and so on...

Comment: I want to modify the one under <test-case title="Power-Consist-Message">, how to do that? am very new to programming, please help me... otherwise is there any way to modify all occurances of <mtn:ttl>some value<\/mtn:ttl> to <mtn:ttl>some other value<\/mtn:ttl>

Comment: By default, the sub! method will only modify the first instance found; if you can guarantee that the first mtn:ttl is the one you want, then you can just use the sub! method as I described.

If you want to modify every single mtn:ttl tag, you can use the gsub! method instead (that is, it's a "global substitite", not just a "substitute").

Comment: hi, I just want to modify the string <mtn:ttl>some other value<\/mtn:ttl>, which is under/after string <test-case title="Power-Consist-Message">, how to do file manipulation in that case? Please help me am in need

Comment: You can modify the regular expression further to do that, using lookbehind (btw, you'll need at least Ruby 1.9.0 to do this). The regex to match the first <mtn:ttl> value after <test-case title="Power-Consist-Message"> with lookbehind would be: /(?<=<Power-Consist-Message>.+?)<mtn:ttl>.+?<\/mtn:ttl>/

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake, it would be /(?<=<test-case title="Power-Consist-Message">.+?)<mtn:ttl>.+?<\/mtn:ttl>/

Comment: BTW, if you'll need do a lot of this sort of automated text manipulation stuff, I strongly recommend reading up on regular expressions. They look pretty ugly when you're not used to them, but it's pretty easy to write your own, and they're endlessly useful for all sorts of things.